# Bootstrap, FontAwesome, RoR setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Is there a way to quickly setup a Bootstrap/FontAwesome/[insert other cool service/framework] setup on a RoR project w/ out having to install each one separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) script.

It will automate and install many extensions/gems in a new RoR project, and is also extensible by creating new "recipies."

I don't remember it having FontAwsome, but it has many recipies, including Bootstrap, Zurb Foundation, and others.